# Return calculated value from enum

Tags: java, enums

please my question are two and very simple

1. misinterpret enum as is
2. this idea missing some important abstraction in my code

code example, where `oprt.calc(x, y)` isn't compilable, with warning  `cannot find symbol`

```
public enum Operation {

    PLUS {
        public double calc(double x, double y) {
            return x + y;
        }
    },
    MINUS {
        public double calc(double x, double y) {
            return x - y;
        }
    },
    MULTILPLE {
        public double calc(double x, double y) {
            return x * y;
        }
    },
    DIVIDED_BY {
        public double calc(double x, double y) {
            return x / y;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double x = 15.25;
        double y = 24.50;
        for (Operation oprt : Operation.values()) {
            System.out.println(x + " " + oprt + " " 
                    + y + " = " + oprt.calc(x, y));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, this sounds like a perfekt application of Lambda Expressions, an upcomming feature of Java 8. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: The error message I get when I load this into eclipse is `The method calc(double, double) is undefined for the type Operation` which points to the solutions others have provided below.

Comment: +1 I didn't knew that there is something like this with enum.

Comment: @JJPA,  they can also have instance variables and constructor. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Enums are almost normal classes but they cannot be extended more than once. If you declare any method in an enum effectively you create an inner subclass of the main enum. You do not need to declare the method abstract, in may contain default impl (so adding enums could be simpler sometimes). Having more than 2 enums w/ overridden methods (usually) forces the JVM into virtual calls that can still be inlined via inline-caches until you get 6-7 ones and then it yeild pure virtual call that prevents a lot of optimizations, sometimes doing switch/case might be faster contrary on one's insticts...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you miss is abstract declaration of calc() method:

```
enum Operation {

  PLUS {
      public double calc(double x, double y) {
          return x + y;
      }
  },
  MINUS {
      public double calc(double x, double y) {
          return x - y;
      }
  },
  MULTILPLE {
      public double calc(double x, double y) {
          return x * y;
      }
  },
  DIVIDED_BY {
      public double calc(double x, double y) {
          return x / y;
      }
  };

  **public abstract double calc(double x, double y);**

  public static void main(String args[]) {
      double x = 15.25;
      double y = 24.50;
      for (Operation oprt : Operation.values()) {
          System.out.println(x + " " + oprt + " " 
                  + y + " = " + oprt.calc(x, y));
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to declare an abstract method `double calc(double x, double y)` in the enum directly, and override it in every enum member.

Comment: can you please to clarify 2nd part from your answer, `and override it in every enum member`, is there something safer, another additional, or ..., in compare with the answer by @Adam Dyga

Comment: No. The code of Adam is what I meant. I like adding the @Override annotation on methods overriding another method, to have an error from the compiler if the base method is renamed, deleted, or changes its signature, but in this particular case, it isn't really useful, except for documentation purpose.

Comment: :-) sorry wasn't me clear annotation from that, you are right IDE notified about

Answer (score 3):

You are overriding `calc()`, while you have no original `calc()` method. Either declare an abstract method:

```
public abstract double calc(double x, double y);
```

or declare a concrete method with a default implementation:

```
public double calc(double x, double y)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax to use enum methods is:

```
private enum Operation {
    PLUS, MINUS, MULTILPLE, DIVIDED_BY;

    public double calc(double x, double y) {
        switch (this) {
        case PLUS:
            return x + y;
        case MINUS:
            return x - y;
        case MULTILPLE:
            return x * y;
        case DIVIDED_BY:
            return x / y;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    double x = 15.25;
    double y = 24.50;
    for (Operation oprt : Operation.values()) {
        System.out.println(x + " " + oprt + " " + y + " = "
                + oprt.calc(x, y));
    }

}
```

Comment: Java enums can have abstract methods that can be implemented for each specific enum value; I think that is preferable over your solution with a switch in most cases

Comment: can you please explain why the abstract method needs to be present? what is the 'semantic' for this enum design decision?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile because currently, the `calc` method only exists in each of the possible values of your `enum` - but it does not exist on the *type* `Operation` itself. That's why your compiler (and mine) doesn't accept it.

So, you need to define the method in the *type*. Maybe something like this:

```
public abstract double calc(double x, double y);
```

Your enum values (`PLUS`, `MINUS`, `MULTIPLE` and `DIVIDED_BY` each implement that method.

Answer (score 2):

```
public double calc(double x, double y){}
```

is same as

```
private double calc(double x,double y){}
```

unless you add `calc()` method to the enum `Operation`.As per JLS:

```
Instance methods declared in these class bodies are may be invoked outside 
the enclosing enum type only if they override accessible methods in 
the enclosing enum type.
```

So basically , the type of `oprt` is `Operation` and as `Operation`doesn't have any declaration for method called `double calc(double x,double y)`, you cannot invoke the method using `oprt`. In short the methods defined in class bodies should be overridden methods, for them to be accessible outside.